# Viber in Pidgin Integration

Tags: pidgin, viber

How can I integrate Viber into Pidgin?

I have Viber registered and both Viber and Pidgin installed.

Comment: It can't be done.

Comment: Pidgin doesn't support viber.

Answer (score 3):

Neither I nor [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22viber%22+%22pidgin%22) are aware of any integration of Viber into Pidgin. Therefore it's likely impossible to achieve what you want at the moment (without writing code yourself).

On top of that, I believe it unlikely that we will see a Pidgin plug-in for Viber integration in the near future for the following reasons unless Viber changes its policy:

- Viber is closed-source which makes a replication of its client software difficult.
- While Viber [provides an API for its service](https://developers.viber.com/api/rest-bot-api/index.html) it is restricted to [public accounts](https://developers.viber.com/public-accounts/index.html).

Comment: What's a relation between you, Google and Pidgin with Viber? The root of your awareness pessimism is unclear from the answer.

Comment: The relation between me and Google is that I used Google to look for a relation between Pidgin and Viber. The relation ship between Google and `"pidgin" "viber"` is none that points to a Viber integration into Pidgin. (Your question is the top search result.) The same goes for me and `"pidgin" "viber"`. The relation between Pidgin and Viber is none (beyond some functional similarity), unfortunately.

Comment: Sorry that you don't like my comment so much that even -1 a question after that.

Comment: @Zon: Huh? I didn't cast a vote on your question. Could you please stop the unwarranted *ad hominem*? If you have any material criticism please say so.